# What does "the reporting obligations prescribed by national regulations" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning, legalese

I do not know what the bolded text says although I know the meaning of every single word! Would someone kindly help me?

> Tourism professionals, insofar as it depends on them, should show concern, in cooperation with the public authorities, for the security and safety, accident prevention, health protection and food safety of those who seek their services; likewise, they should ensure the existence of suitable systems of insurance and assistance; **they should accept the reporting obligations prescribed by national regulations** and pay fair compensation in the event of failure to observe their contractual obligations;
> ([Source](http://ethics.unwto.org/en/content/global-code-ethics-tourism-article-6))

What are the reporting obligations prescribed by national regulations?!

Comment: This post discusses another U.N. document: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47979

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> they should accept the reporting obligations prescribed by national regulations

They should produce reports in accordance with obligations prescribed by nation-wide regulatory bodies.

If some national regulator (a ministry or a federal agency or whatever) says that companies engaged in the business  of tourism should submit or publish such and such report, probably at some regular intervals, and this report should be produced in accordance with some requirements, then they (tourism professionals) should listen to this and accept this.

For example, the Tourism Ministry issues some decree saying "All tourism companies are obligated to report once a year on their insurance statistics. The reports should comply with such-and-such standards". The tourism companies surely should accept this and produce the necessary reports.

Answer (score 4):

SUPPLEMENTARY to CopperKettle's ANSWER
A little syntactic analysis of this clause may help you struggle through sentences like this in the future.

1. The basic structure is

   `SUBJECT   :` They
   `VERB      :` should accept
   `DIR OBJ   :` the reporting obligations prescribed by national regulations.
2. What is probably giving you trouble is the structure of that Direct Object. Its 'head' is *obligations*, which has a determiner and two modifiers:

   `DETERMINER:` the
   `MODIFIER  :` reporting
   `HEAD      :` obligations
   `MODIFIER  :` prescribed by national regulations.

   The first modifier is a *gerund*: the *-ing* form of the verb *report* employed as a noun meaning "the action of making a report". That noun is employed *attributively*: it is placed before the noun as a modifier in the same way as the nouns *accident*, *health* and *food* are placed before *prevention*, *protection* and *safety* earlier in the paragraph. *Reporting obligations* tells us what *kind* of obligations: "obligations to report something-or-other".

   The second modifier is understood by many modern grammarians as a *reduced relative clause*: that is, it is an ordinary relative clause from which the relative pronoun (here *which* or *that*) and the following form of the verb *BE* have been deleted<sup>†</sup>:

   > <s>which are</s> prescribed by national regulations.

   (*I don't particularly care for this analysis, but it* does *accurately paraphrase what such participle phrases mean, and there's no actual harm in your thinking of these constructions that way.*)

   This tells us *which* 'reporting obligations' should be accepted: the ones which national regulations prescribe.

---

<sup>†</sup> <sub>This 'transformation' is often called ***Whiz*** deletion, a snappy name in which the *Wh* piece stands for any relative pronoun, because most of these start with *wh-*, and the *iz* piece reflects the pronunciation of *is*, a form of the verb *BE*. The first generation of transformational grammarians delighted in this sort of wordplay, which stands in contrast to the stuffy Latinisms which dominate academic writing.</sub>

Comment: Would you introduce me a good, comprehensive me on transformation? I eagerly need a reliable practical source explaining the major transformations which makes understanding the sense difficult!

Comment: @Juya Most of what I know I learned from McCawley, *Syntactic Phenomena in English*.